# What does this symbol mean (set theory)

Tags: predicate-logic

I hate when I come across symbols I can't recognise or describe because it's nigh-on impossible to google for them, so I hope it's okay to post this here. Does anyone know what this symbol means within the realm of Set Theory/Predicate Logic:

[image]

In this context "WidgetNodule" is a state with the following specification:

[image]

Comment: Did you search [list of math symbols](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols) and/or [list of math symbols by subject](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_mathematical_symbols_by_subject) ?

Comment: Can you say more about the context in which you saw this?  This is certainly not a standard notation broadly in "set theory/predicate logic".

Comment: It almost seems like you are trying to obscure where this came from... Why not tell us the paper/book/whatever, or at least give a relatively complete example of how it is used.

Comment: I couldn't agree more with the above comments about the context. This notation is very familiar to those in the know about Z (see my answer), but there are probably very few such people in the MSE community and it would have been a kindness to the rest of the community to say where you came across your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in the realm of formal specification in computer science: the notation you are looking at is the [Z specification language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z_notation). Z is used for specifying systems by describing their states and state transitions in (a typed) set theory. In Z, $\Xi S$ is an abbreviation meaning that the part $S$ of the state is unchanged by a transition: in this case $\Xi\mathit{WidgetNodule}$ encapsulates the equation $\mathit{seen}' = \mathit{seen}$.